# Bootstrap form tag and ng-class

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to understand why the following wouldn't be the same?

```
<form class="col-xs-2">
<form ng-class="{1:'col-xs-2'}[1]">
```

In first scenario all form fields will be sized to the provided class, but in the second scenario they are not? Is it a bug in the form tag?

Here is my
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3xa68t0/2/)

Thanks for help.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to make a width of form fields different based on a screen resolution. The sample is a simplified version.

Comment: Works fine for me.  You didn't have `ng-app` anywhere.  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h3xa68t0/3/)

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, in reality, I dont have ng-app="" in every template. So, for example, in my template <div ng-class="{1:'form-group col-xs-2'}[1]"> works fine, but the same for the form tag does not.